# Script to copy missing files for Android

Tags: android, bash

ok i am trying to make a script that will copy files from safe location if the file is not found via the checking script so if that file was not found it would activeta another script that would repiar (transfer the files from safe location to the meant path)

```
#!/system/bin/sh

clear
if
    sleep 2
    echo ""
    echo "SPL ENGINE CORE is it installed ?"
    sleep 2
    echo ""
    echo "Checking for SPL ENGINE A.I. CORE ..."
    sleep 1

    if [ -e /system/spl_engine_core ]; then
        echo ""
        echo "SPL ENGINE CORE is installed..."
        sleep 1
    else
        echo ""
        echo "SPL ENGINE CORE binary was not found,please Re-flash SPL Transcender then try again!"
        sleep 1
    then 
    echo""
    echo"Everything is installed."
    echo"SPL Engine is online and working"
else
    echo""
    echo"Some files are missing"
    echo"Initiating repiring protocol"
    echo"AI is making repairs"

    if [""echo"AI is making repairs""]; then
        sh /system/spl_engine_core/secure/files/engine.core/spl_smart_repair_ai.sh; 
        echo "Repair succesfull"
        echo "SPL Core is online again"
    else
        echo ""
        echo "Initiating uninstall"
        sh system/bin/spl_uninstall
        echo"Please reinstall"
exit 0
```

Comment: Please specify the question and narrow the code to the minimal needed amount.

Comment: ok i am trying to make a script that will copy files from safe location if the file is not found via the checking script

Comment: hey i narrowed it can u look at it now

Comment: This isn't really a code review site, can you specify what actual issue you're having (i.e. what isn't working)? Glancing at it, I'm not sure if something got lost when copied onto SO, but you have some errant if/else's floating around.

Comment: it says if is unmatched so i think it doesnt get what i want it to do i want it to check for files and if they are not where they should be run another script that will place them back i just narrowed the code that searches for many files

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/